# Proper way to make advanced search in django

Tags: python, django, search, filter, model

After reading and testing many posts, answers and tips, I decided to write down the way I made my search in my Django project to help others. *It's in hungarian.*

[image]

**models.py**

First thing first, I have a model (called `Igeny`)with multiple attributes:

```
class Igeny(models.Model):
    Cim = models.CharField(max_length=150, verbose_name="Igény címe")
    Igenylo = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name="Igénylő", blank=True, null=True)
    Igenyles_tartalom = models.TextField(verbose_name="Igénylés leírása")
    Status = models.IntegerField(default=0, verbose_name="Igénylés status")
    Allapot = models.CharField(default="Piszkozat", max_length=255, verbose_name="Igénylés állapota")
    UID = models.CharField(max_length=150, default="")
    Email = models.EmailField(default="xyz@xyz.hu")
    Phone = models.CharField(max_length=50, default="", null=True, verbose_name="Telefonos elérhetőség")
    Indoklas = models.TextField(default="", verbose_name="Igény indoklása")
```

**views.py**

In the views.py, I first filtered the list of results with the `Q object`, then passed the results to a self created filter called `IgenyFilter`:

```
def search_results(request):
    igeny_list = Igeny.objects.filter(Q(Ugyvezeto=request.user.profile) | Q(BeszerzesVezeto=request.user.profile) | Q(Igazgato=request.user.profile) | Q(EgysegVezeto=request.user.profile) | Q(Igenylo=request.user)).order_by('Status')
    igeny_filter = IgenyFilter(request.GET, queryset=igeny_list)
    igeny_lista = igeny_filter.qs.order_by('-Cim')
    return render(request, 'catalog/search_results.html', {'filter': igeny_filter, 'igeny': igeny_lista})
```

For this `IgenyFilter`, I made a filter.py:

**filter.py**

```
class IgenyFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    Cim = django_filters.CharFilter(field_name="Cim",
                                    lookup_expr='icontains',
                                    label='Igény címe (tartalmazza)')  # Mindet listázza, amiben benne van a beírt szó
    Igenyles_tartalom = django_filters.CharFilter(field_name="Igenyles_tartalom",
                                                  lookup_expr='icontains',
                                                  label='Igénylés tartalma (tartalmazza)')  # Mindet listázza, amiben benne van a beírt szó

    Igenylo = django_filters.CharFilter(field_name="Igenylo__first_name",
                                        lookup_expr='icontains',
                                        label='Igénylő neve')  # Mindet listázza, amiben benne van a beírt szó

    Allapot = django_filters.CharFilter(field_name="Allapot",
                                        lookup_expr='icontains',
                                        label='Igénylés állapota (tartalmazza)')  # Mindet listázza, amiben benne van a beírt szó

    Brutto = django_filters.NumberFilter(field_name="Brutto",
                                        lookup_expr='gte',
                                        label='Igénylés bruttó értéke (nagyobb-egyenlő)')
```

As you can see in the attached image, those 5 attributes are the same as the filter fields.

**urls.py**

In the urls.py, the name must be the same as the views's name (`search_results`):

```
path('search/', views.search_results, name='search_results'),
```

So, if you get there (to this url) from another html page with

```
<form class="form-inline" style="margin-left: 5px">
    <a href="{% url 'search_results' %}" class="btn btn-outline-success-hm my-2 my-sm-0"
                           style="margin-left: 1em" type="button"> Keresés </a>
</form>
```

And the search_results html page looks like:

**html**

It consists of a form, where you can display the labels of the attribute fields and the textboxes:

```
<form method="GET">
     {% csrf_token %}
  <div class="well">
        <h4 style="margin-top: 0">Keresés eredménye</h4>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="form-group col-sm-4 col-md-3">
                {{ filter.form.Cim.label_tag }}
                {% render_field filter.form.Cim class="form-control" %}
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-sm-4 col-md-3">
                {{ filter.form.Igenylo.label_tag }}
                {% render_field filter.form.Igenylo class="form-control" %}
            </div>
             <div class="form-group col-sm-4 col-md-3">
                {{ filter.form.SzervezetiEgyseg.label_tag }}
                {% render_field filter.form.SzervezetiEgyseg class="form-control" %}
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-sm-4 col-md-3">
                {{ filter.form.Igenyles_tartalom.label_tag }}
                {% render_field filter.form.Igenyles_tartalom class="form-control" %}
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-sm-4 col-md-3">
                {{ filter.form.Brutto.label_tag }}
                {% render_field filter.form.Brutto class="form-control" %}
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-sm-4 col-md-3">
                {{ filter.form.Allapot.label_tag }}
                {% render_field filter.form.Allapot class="form-control" %}
            </div>
        </div>     
    </div>
```

There is the Search button in the bottom:

```
<div style="padding-left: 200px; padding-bottom: 20px">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span> Keresés
            </button>
        </div>
</form>
```

The next content is a table with the results:
These are the names of each column:

```
<table class="table table-bordered">
    <thead>
    <tr style="background-color: #0e1f2d">
        <th style="color: #aeb189">Igény megnevezése</th>
        <th style="color: #aeb189">Igénylő neve</th>
        <th style="color: #aeb189">Szervezeti Egység neve</th>
        <th style="color: #aeb189">Igénylés tartalma</th>
        <th style="color: #aeb189">Bruttó ár</th>
        <th style="color: #aeb189">Igénylés állapota</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
```

And in the body section, the results are shown with a `for loop`:

```
    <tbody>
    {% for igeny in filter.qs %}
    <tr style="background-color: #3C4D37">
        <td><a style="color: #3486eb" href="{{ igeny.get_absolute_url }}">{{ igeny.Cim }}</a></td>
        <td style="color: #aeb189">{{ igeny.Igenylo.last_name }} {{ igeny.Igenylo.first_name }}</td>
        <td style="color: #aeb189">{{ igeny.SzervezetiEgyseg }}</td>
        <td style="color: #aeb189">{{ igeny.Igenyles_tartalom }}</td>
        <td style="color: #aeb189" align="right">{{ igeny.Brutto }} Ft</td>
        <td style="color: #aeb189">{{ igeny.Allapot }}</td>
    </tr>
```

If there is no result for the given filters, it shows us:

```
{% empty %}
    <tr>
    <td style="color: #aeb189" colspan="5">Nincs találat</td>
    </tr>
 {% endfor %}
 </tbody>
 </table>
```

I hope I can help someone. Sorry for my bad English.